# Dateformat in tt_news

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tt-news

I use tt_news version 3.4.0 and I'd like to change the Dateformat of the News in for example: September 2013

Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try...

```
plugin.tt_news {
  displayList.date_stdWrap.date = j F Y
  displayLatest.date_stdWrap.date = j F Y
  displaySingle.date_stdWrap.date = j F Y
}
```

...or...

```
plugin.tt_news {
  displayList.date_stdWrap.strftime = %e %B %Y
  displayLatest.date_stdWrap.strftime = %e %B %Y
  displaySingle.date_stdWrap.strftime = %e %B %Y
}
```

Comment: This sets the format to e.g. "1 January 2013". If you really want only "January 2013", remove "j" or "%e" from the format code.